# Symfony 6 problem when uploading files in production

Tags: symfony, upload, public-html

With my project symfony, when deploy my website on hostinger, i have a problem with my uploading files. The files i want to upload on my website must be store in "/public_html/css/images/" but symfony create a new directory named "/public/css/images/"
I try to resolve this since a few weeks...

help me please ? I'm totaly lost.

[[[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9PaZ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz3hR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPhvF.png)

[My service configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oym5B.png)

[The files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LsgU.png)

Comment: Please copy paste code directly here rather than screenshoting it. This also seems to be incomplete code, unless that's all you have - it does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename public_html directory to public_html.bac and then public directory to public_html. If this is not possible copy all files and directories inside public to public_html. This should work as described in Symfony docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory